# PHP move_uploaded_file directory and mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, insert

So this works:

```
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
   } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
     }
```

and this also works

```
  echo imagejpeg($image,null,30);
  $image = ob_get_clean();
  ob_end_clean();
  $image = addslashes($image);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO zzimages (`user_id`,`imit`)
  VALUES ('9','$image')";
```

but when I try and use the $image to insert into directory, it does not work. I need to use $image because it represents a properly rotated image.

So this does not work, please advise:

```
     if (move_uploaded_file($image, $target_file)) {
     echo "this needs to work"}
```

Comment: you need to make sure that the destination $target_file directory has permission to move file (able to write to the destination directory) and is owned by the web server user apache (in CentOS) or www-data (in Ubuntu).

Comment: like i said,  move_uploaded_works when I reference $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"] but I need to reference $image as the upload file.